# Automatic Sorting right after adding a record without refreshing the webpage in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I am working on an application in which I have a section for each product as shown in the below picture. I am using knockout js and OData to add a record

[image]

When I click on the copy button in C5 on a record, for now it is copying a the record I copied and adding it at the end of the section C5. But I would like the record to be added right below the record which I had hit the copy button.

As for now I am sorting the section using OrderBy in LINQ but that works only when I refresh the webpage.

**LING code:**

```
 public override IQueryable<CanadianCrude> Get()
        {

            return db.CanadianCrudes.OrderByDescending(c => c.Term).ThenBy(c=>c.Bid);
        }
```

**Knockout and OData:**

```
var CanadianCrudeViewModel = function (CanadianContext) {
    var self = this;
    self.canadiancrudes = ko.observableArray();
 self.copy = function (canadiancrude) {
        var payload = {
            Id: canadiancrude.Id, Term: "", Product: canadiancrude.Product, Location: "", Pipeline: "",
            BidCP: "", BidVolume: "", Index: "", Bid: "0.0", Offer: "0.0",
            OfferVolume: "", OfferCP: ""
        };
        $.ajax({
            url: '/odata/Canadiancrudes',
            type: 'POST',
            // data: ko.toJSON(payload),
            data: JSON.stringify(payload),
            contentType: 'application/json',
            dataType: 'json'
        });
    }
$.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        url: '/odata/Canadiancrudes',
        data: ko.toJSON(self.products),
        async: false,
        success: function (data) {
            self.datainput((ko.utils.arrayMap(data.value, function (canadiancrude) {
                var obsCanadianCrude = {
                    Id: canadiancrude.Id,
                    Term: ko.observable(canadiancrude.Term),
                    Product: canadiancrude.Product,
                    Location: ko.observable(canadiancrude.Location),
                    Pipeline: ko.observable(canadiancrude.Pipeline),
                    BidCP: ko.observable(canadiancrude.BidCP),
                    BidVolume: ko.observable(canadiancrude.BidVolume),
                    Index: ko.observable(canadiancrude.Index),
                    Bid: ko.observable(canadiancrude.Bid),
                    Offer: ko.observable(canadiancrude.Offer),
                    OfferVolume: ko.observable(canadiancrude.OfferVolume),
                    OfferCP: ko.observable(canadiancrude.OfferCP),
                    Edit: ko.observable(false),

                    Locked: ko.observable(canadiancrude.Locked)
                }
                self.watchModel(obsCanadianCrude, self.modelChanged);
                return obsCanadianCrude;
            })));
        }
    });
 var viewModel = new CanadianCrudeViewModel(canadiancrudeSignalR);
 ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

**View**

```
    <table class="productTable">

        <thead>

            <tr>

                <th>Term</th>
                <th>Location</th>
                <th>Pipeline</th>
                <th>Bid C/P</th>
                <th>Index</th>
                <th>Bid Volume</th>
                 <th>Bid</th>
                <th>Offer</th>
                <th>Offer Volume</th>
                <th>Offer C/P</th>
                <th colspan="3">Actions</th>
                @*  <th></th>
                <th></th>*@

            </tr>

        </thead>

        <tr>
<script type="text/html" id="read-template">

    <td data-bind="text: Term"></td>
    <td data-bind="text: Location"></td>
    <td data-bind="text: Pipeline"></td>
    <td data-bind="text: BidCP"></td>
     <td data-bind="text: Index"></td>
    <td data-bind="text: BidVolume"></td>

    <td class="highlight" data-bind="text: Bid"></td>
    <td class="highlight" data-bind="text: Offer"></td>
    <td data-bind="text: OfferVolume"></td>
    <td data-bind="text: OfferCP"></td>



    <td class="actioncells">
        @*<a href="#" title="Copy" data-bind="click: $root.copy">
            <img src= '@Url.Content("~/Images/add.png")' /></a>*@
        <a class="btn" title="Copy" data-bind="click: $root.copy">Copy</a>
    </td>

    <td class="actioncells">
        @*<a href="#" title="Edit" data-bind="click: $root.edit">
            <img src= '@Url.Content("~/Images/edit.png")' /></a>*@
        <a class="btn btn-success" title="Edit" data-bind="click: $root.edit">Edit</a>
    </td>


    <td class="actioncells">
        @*<a href="#" title="Delete" data-bind="click: $root.remove">
        <img src= '@Url.Content("~/Images/delete.png")' /></a>*@
        <a class="btn btn-danger" title="Delete" data-bind="click: $root.remove">Delete</a>

    </td>
</script>
</tr>

        </tbody>
</table>
```

Can anyone suggest me a good way to do that.

Comment: Just call .sort() on your observable array...  You can do it either in the view model or the view.

Comment: How can I do it in the view

Comment: Call .sort on your observableArray...  You aren't showing any view specific code in your question so I can't add it

Comment: I was not clear about it but I have added(edited) all the code I have for it just in case

Comment: This is nothing but a simple JS problem. Despite using Web APIs, etc., at this particular point in your code, you merely have a JS array structure that you need to sort. See the knockout docs for how to sort an observableArray: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html#pop_push_shift_unshift_reverse_sort_splice

Comment: I'd use a computed observable to display the data. The computed observable would contain your `canadiancrudes` observable array, but it would be sorted. That way, any time any new data is added to `canadiancrudes` it will automatically be displayed sorted